# MySQL out of sort memory

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in MYSQL table where i have to paginate through 4 rows at a time.

To do this I use the command below where i increase X from 0 by 4 until i reach the end of the data.

The command works for X=0 and X=4, when i reach X=8 i get the error #1038 - out of sort memory, i tried increasing it to 256K but same result.

Anybody know how to solve? Im using PHP

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE (scope=0) AND (id='6')) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE (scope=0) AND (id<=1000))) as total ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT X,4
```

Comment: In a normalised environment, `DISTINCT *` is an oxymoron

Comment: Do you think DISTINCT is causing it?

Comment: Distinct ain't doin nuthin

Comment: Do you know why i get error when X=8 and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but your query seems to be functionally identical to this:

```
SELECT columns
     , you
     , actually 
     , want
  FROM table 
 WHERE scope = 0
   AND id<=1000
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp DESC 
 LIMIT X,4
```

Comment: Thanks!, i simply took out DISTINCT from my original post and it worked!!!